# Wagtail How to get the value of an orderable

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am a relative newcomer to programming Wagtail
My attempt is a cascaded application where the title is formed from the relation to the underlying element.
The cascade should be structured like this
Fach --> Reihe --> Ebene --> Behaelter
My models.py

```
class NoTitleForm(WagtailAdminPageForm):
    title = forms.CharField(required=False, disabled=True, help_text=('Title is autogenerated'))
    slug = forms.CharField(required=False, disabled=True, help_text=('Slug is autogenerated'))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.initial['title']:
            self.initial['title'] = _('auto-generated-title')
        if not self.initial['slug']:
            self.initial['slug'] = _('auto-generated-slug')


class ReihePage(Page):
    base_form_class = NoTitleForm

    content_panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(
            [
                InlinePanel("Fach", label="Fach", min_num=0, max_num=10),
            ]
                      ),

        FieldPanel('title'),
        FieldPanel('slug'),
        ]

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        new_title = "anzahl from Fach" + "title from Fach" <--** How to get the values from the InlinePanel**
        
        self.title = new_title
        self.slug = slugify(new_title) 

class ReihePageOrderable(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(ReihePage, related_name="Fach", null=True)
    fach = models.ForeignKey("Fachpage", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    anzahl = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    
    
class FachPage(Page):
    laenge = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Länge in mm')
    breite = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Breite in mm')

    content_panels = [
        # FieldPanel('bezeichnung'),
        FieldPanel('laenge'),
        FieldPanel('breite'),
        FieldPanel('title'),
        FieldPanel('slug'),
        ]

    parent_page_types = ['FachIndexPage']

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('laenge', 'breite')

    def clean(self):
        """Override the values of title and slug before saving."""
        super().clean()
        a = str(self.laenge)
        b = str(self.breite)
        new_title = "Fach" + " " + a + "x" + b + " mm"
        self.title = new_title
        self.slug = slugify(new_title)
    base_form_class = NoTitleForm
```

I read the documentation on the wagtail-site
I try a function with get_context and many more

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You want to make a Wagtail setup where each page's title is based on the elements it's related to. If I got it right, your ReihePage should have a title made up of how many FachPage instances it has and what their titles are, correct?
To do this, you need to get the related FachPage instances from your ReihePage. You can do this by querying the related FachPage instances within the ReihePage model.

```py
class ReihePage(Page):
    base_form_class = NoTitleForm

    content_panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            InlinePanel("fach_relation", label="Fach", min_num=0, max_num=10),
        ]),
        FieldPanel('title'),
        FieldPanel('slug'),
    ]

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        fach_instances = self.fach_relation.all()
        fach_count = len(fach_instances)
        fach_titles = [fach_instance.title for fach_instance in fach_instances]
        new_title = f"Count from Fach: {fach_count}, Titles: {', '.join(fach_titles)}"
        self.title = new_title
        self.slug = slugify(new_title)


class ReihePageOrderable(Orderable):
    page = ParentalKey(ReihePage, related_name="fach_relation")
    fach = models.ForeignKey("FachPage", on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    anzahl = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help
Now i got an Attribute Error
 AttributeError at /admin/pages/add/lager/reihepage/3/
'ReihePageOrderable' object has no attribute 'title'